# Insert data into database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

This is my first Application with database, I hope that someone can help me to understand this problem. I have this insert method:

```
 public long insertData(String name, int password){

      ....
        contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);

        return  db.insert(DBHelper.TABle_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
```

I can insert few data with this method, but what about if I have thousands of rows? how can I insert all these data into database? where can I write all these data, in extra class or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you'll need to do some sort of iteration.
Efficiency can be gained by performing a bulk *transaction*. Here's an example:

```
public int bulkInsert(@NonNull ContentValues[] values) {
    int insertCount = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db = mSqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        for (ContentValues value : values) {
            if (db.insertOrThrow(tableName, null, value) == -1) {
                throw new Exception("Unknown error while inserting entry in database.");
            }
            insertCount++;
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "An error occurred while bulk-inserting database entries.\n" + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    return insertCount;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why should I need Uri, I don't use here the network.

Comment: My method just happens to be part of a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html), I'll edit it to simplify.

Comment: @SamJoos In case you are interested in learning more about content providers, here is a [nice resource](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) Although android documentation suggests content providers be used only for sharing data between applications, I've found them to be super useful for sharing data within a single application because it decouples code that processes and inserts data from code that simply displays it nicely. Anyway, I'm glad my answer helped!

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'bulk load' facility that I'm aware of.
You'd just have to spin through the list, and insert the items.

You might want to think about why you're potentially trying to insert thousands of items into a database on a hardware-limited device like a phone or a tablet.

Might it be better to put the data on a server, and create an API that you can use to load data (for display) by pages?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it the same way, that you do with few data, you only need to catch the thousands rows to insert into your database using your method, you can use asyntask, or a service to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same method to insert any amount of records, whether it's 1 or 1,000. Use a loop to call your insert method and add your records to your database. Consider putting your database executions in an AsyncTask to prevent your UI thread from hanging.

Your data can come from anywhere, as long as it's formatted to fit your function parameters `String, int`